# Information not being saved to the database when i click the button

Tags: android

I am trying to save my information entered in my fields into the database but every time I click the button the app runs only the progress dialog. It also doesn't take me to the next activity nor does it save my input information into the database. What is going wrong?

My class code:

```
package com.example.profmox.venmart;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputEditText mDisName;
    private TextInputEditText mEmail;
    private TextInputEditText mPassword;
    private Button mRegister;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.reg_appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Account");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDisName = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_disName);
        mEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        mPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_create);

        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String display_name = mDisName.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display_name) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Registering user");
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we register your account");
                    mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                    registerUser(display_name,email,password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(final String display_name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            String uid = current_user.getUid();

                            mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers").child(uid);

                            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                            userMap.put("name", display_name);
                            userMap.put("status"," ");
                            userMap.put("image", "default");
                            userMap.put("thumb-iamge","default");

                            mDatabse.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Intent main_Intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        main_Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(main_Intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/reg_appbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_disName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Display Name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Create Account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Create A New Account"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_appbar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and below are the dependencies i am using:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get an answer faster if you improve your question. Take a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this toast:

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

use this:

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if you want to know why the registration failed.  
The reasons would be: a user has already been registered with the same email, a weak password or...

Comment: Did you try it? So what was the message?